# Java Server Client Semantics

Tags: java, android, sockets

I am new to java and network programming for the most part.  I want to write a program that automatically backs up my texts to my computer whenever my phone connects to my home wifi.

I am working on creating java classes that will handle sending data over the network.  Using some questions found here, I came up with this implementation but I have some questions regarding some of the methods used in what I learned from.

Two Questions Regarding this code

1. I totally used a question from SO for the send methods in my client.  The sendText uses a new thread, but the sendFile doesn't.  Any particular reason why?

<strike>2.  At which point in the code does the server actually know when there has been a message sent to the port?  Is it at the method `accept()` call or is it when the BufferStream `readLine()` is checked?  Does accept just grab data and throw it into the buffer?  null implying the data grabbed was not a signal sent from a client?</strike>

2. Does the accept() method block execution of the code until a connection attempt is made from a client?

Thanks!

## KServ

```
//Used to launch the server 
public class KServ {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        if (args.length != 1) {
            System.err.println("Usage: java KServ <port number>");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        int port = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        KServer server = new KServer(port);

        while (true) { //added this to keep the server polling for new data
           server.run();
        }

    }

}
```

## KServer

```
//Server class.  Should handle data incoming

import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class KServer {

    private int port;

    public KServer(int PORT) {
        port = PORT;
    }

    public void run() {

        try (
            ServerSocket sSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
            Socket cSocket = sSocket.accept();
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(cSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(cSocket.getInputStream()));
        ) {
            String input;
            while ((input = in.readLine()) != null) {

                System.out.println(input);

            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Exception caught when trying to listen on port " + port + " or listening for a connection");
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }

    }

}
```

## Client

```
//launches KClient object and uses it to send input from console to the server

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Client {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if (args.length != 2) {
            System.err.println("Usage: java Client <ip number> <port number>");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        String ip = args[0];
        int port = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
        KClient client = new KClient(ip,port);

        String msg;
        Scanner inStream = new Scanner(System.in);

        while((msg = inStream.nextLine()).length() > 0) {
            client.sendText(msg);
        }

    }
}
```

## KClient

```
//Will be used to establish connection with server and send data from phone
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

public class KClient {

    private String server;
    private int port;

    public KClient(String Server,int Port) {
        server = Server;
        port = Port;
    }

    public void sendFile(String fileName) {

        File file = new File(fileName);

        FileInputStream fileInputStream;
        BufferedInputStream bufferedInputStream;
        OutputStream outputStream;

        try {
            client = new Socket(server,port);

            byte[] bytes = new byte[(int) file.length()];
            fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
            bufferedInputStream = new BufferedInputStream(fileInputStream);

            bufferedInputStream.read(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
            outputStream = client.getOutputStream();

            outputStream.write(bytes,0,bytes.length);
            outputStream.flush();
            bufferedInputStream.close();
            outputStream.close();
            client.close();

        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
    }

    private Socket client;
    private OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter;

    public void sendText(String msg) {
        System.out.println("Send Message!");
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                try {
                    client = new Socket(server,port);
                    outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(client.getOutputStream(), "ISO-8859-1");
                    outputStreamWriter.write(msg);
                    outputStreamWriter.flush();
                    outputStreamWriter.close();
                } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }

    BufferedReader inStream;

    public boolean Shake() {

        try {
            client = new Socket(server,port);
            inStream = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));


        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return true;

    }

}
```

Comment: I'm going to close this as too broad, because what you're really asking for is an explanation of how networking works, the nature of TCP, and effective designs for it.  They write books on these topics.

Comment: I will say your server code has issues-  it won't handle multiple connections at the same time.  For anything other than a non-trivial example you do not want to do work on the same thread after accept-  you want to pass that socket to another thread and get back to calling accept to get the next connection ASAP.

Comment: Thank you!  I realize my question was broad.  Can I remove some of it and ask a couple specific questions?

Comment: Of course.  Networking isn't off topic, there's lots of good questions there.  This is just a bit much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1. I totally used a question from SO for the send methods in my client.  The sendText uses a new thread, but the sendFile doesn't.  Any particular reason why?

Unanswerable. Ask the author. Both sends can block. As the file is presumably longer than the text, it would have made more sense to do it the other way round.

> <strike>2.  At which point in the code does the server actually know when there has been a message sent to the port?  Is it at the method `accept()` call</strike>

No.

> <strike>or is it when the BufferStream `readLine()` is checked?</strike>

Yes.

> <strike>Does accept just grab data and throw it into the buffer?</strike>

No. It grabs a *connection* and returns it as a socket. Nothing to do with data whatsoever.

> <strike>null implying the data grabbed was not a signal sent from a client?</strike>

You seem to be actually asking about `BufferedReader.readLine()` here, not `ServerSocket.accept()`, which doesn't return null. `readLine()` returns null when there is no pending data to be read and the peer has closed the connection.

> 2. Does the accept() method block execution of the code until a connection attempt is made from a client?

More or less. It blocks until there is a complete connection waiting to be accepted, which isn't quite the same thing, as there is a queue.

I will add that you have copied, or written, some truly terrible code here. There are much better examples.

Comment: I did post a comment on the answer asking why he chose only to thread one, and yes, I assumed the file transfer would have been better to thread, but I know that I don't know things.

Thanks for your answers.  And yes, while I'm quite certain this is terrible code, I'm feelin pretty good that I used java to create sockets that communicate.  Considering 3 days ago I've never used a socket and 3 months ago I'd never used java, I'm quite amused.